# How is the 'obj' parameter passed to Permission class function in Django Rest Framework?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

According to Django Rest Framework [documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/), when creating a custom permission the
`has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj)`
function takes `obj` parameter. I guess that `obj` is the requested object, but my question is:
**How does it get passed to this function if permissions are checked before the View code runs?**

Comment: What makes you think they are checked before the view runs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say you have the following view in you DRF api:

```
class MyModelRetieveApiView(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    queryset = MyModel.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MyModelSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication,)
```

you have not to pass any object, DRF will pass an instance of MyModel as obj for you. So if you intend to override `has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj)` just deal with obj as django model instance returned by the `Queryset` for your model `MyModel`.

Comment: why is there a view argument in the has_object_permission ?